# Facebook style image gallery

Tags: jquery, facebook, gallery

I am developing a image gallery website and on that site I got a lot of images.
I want to display them in popups just like Facebook does.

I need the following:

1. That the popup resizes to fit the image and the image information.
2. When I hover over the image I need for tags to be shown.
3. Need to be able to paginate from image to image.

Is there a script anywhere that lets me do a replica of the Facebook Image gallery popup?
Is there a solution to meet the requirements. Hopefully in jQuery.

Thankful for all input!

Comment: So, what is your question?  Do you need to know how to make a div on top of other divs?  Do you need to know how to get the size of an element?  Do you need to know how to detect the mouse position?  Do you need to know how to animate with jQuery?

Comment: I am looking for a jQuery based image gallery that hopefully supports all these features. Basically a Facebook image viewer clone.

Comment: I am looking for something like this too..

Answer (score 5):

I found this image gallery and like it.

http://www.maiconmva.com.br/LikeBox/

Comment: is this free? i didn't get any download link

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the answer to this question at:

http://visuallightbox.com/photo-gallery-with-lightbox-simple-html-demo.html

Try any of the demos shown (lots of different options of style!) These are all JQuery!

I've found that they work better than the facebook viewer in that the viewer automatically moves from image to image but with a manual override! Facebook does'nt have an automatic option (Yet!).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

http://css.dzone.com/articles/facebook-photo-gallery